# Serialize Dotnet Collection without Root Element?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, xsd

Consider following serialized xml:

```
<Course>
  <Title>Engineering</Title>
  <Student>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
  </Student>
   ...
</Course>
```

Unfortunately I am not in a position to modify schema. (Ideally I should have wrapped `Student` class into `Students` root element!)

> How do I define entity classes so that serialization could work properly?

I tried following code, but this generates xml with `Students` as wrapper element.

```
public class Course
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `XmlElement` attribute to your `Students` list, like this:

```
public class Course
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Student")]
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```